# Was the spaceship in Lifeforce inspired by the deep-sea vampire squid?

Tags: lifeforce

For some reason, I had a nightmare last night about the cheesy British movie *[Lifeforce](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/)* (1985), which I saw about twenty-five years ago.  Then today, my son was watching *[The Octonauts](http://www.octonauts.com/)*, in particular, the episode about the vampire squid.  He asked me what a real vampire squid looked like, so I showed him some pictures that I quickly found online.

[image: Vampire Squid]

Having had that unaccountable dream about the movie, these pictures reminded me of the (living, vampiric) spaceship in the movie.

[image: Vampire Spaceship]

Now I'm wondering whether the squid, with its webbed tentacles and ominous name, was a specific inspiration for the design of the ship in the film.  (On its trivia page for the movie, IMDB lists, without attribution, that the ship was inspired by an artichoke, but I do not see much resemblance.)

Comment: I can't seem to find the *origin* of the artichoke story, but it's referenced in the maker's commentary. https://filmschoolrejects.com/22-things-we-learned-from-the-lifeforce-commentary-936217329e81/ - "*Sullivan tells Hooper that special effects artist John Dykstra claims to have designed the space vampires’ spaceship modeled on an artichoke. “If John said that,” says Hooper, “I’ve known him to always be an honest and truthful man so it could be.”*"

Comment: Google gives lots of references to the artichoke, so @Valorum is probably right.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - I'm wondering if they're all back-referencing the audio commentary

Comment: I don't have a reference, but to me it always looked like it was supposed to resemble a bat wing, or a solar sail.

Comment: That seems possible. I've assumed that the ship was intended to resemble bat wings.